# Delphi 7 make complains about files not found

Tags: delphi, makefile, package

I've got a BPG file that I've modified to use as a make file for our company's automated build server. In order to get it to work I had to change

```
Uses                       *  Uses
  unit1 in 'unit1.pas'     *   unit1
  unit2 in 'unit2.pas'     *   unit2
   ...                     *    ...
```

in the DPR file to get it to work without the compiler giving me some guff about unit1.pas not found.
This is annoying because I want to use a BPG file to actually see the stuff in my project and every time I add a new unit, it auto-jacks that in 'unitx.pas' into my DPR file.

I'm running `make -f [then some options]`, the DPR's that I'm compiling are not in the same directory as the make file, but I'm not certain that this matters. Everything compiles fine as long as the `in 'unit1.pas` is removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could come from the fact, that the search path in the IDE and the search path of the command line compiler are not the same. If you change the serach path of the command line compiler you might be able to use the exactely same source code as within the IDE.

One possibility to configure the search path for the command-line compiler is to do it in a file called dcc32.cfg. Take a look at the help, there is a short description of dcc32.cfg in the IDE-help.

Answer (score 1):

Well this work-around worked for me.

```
//{$define PACKAGE}
{$ifdef PACKAGE}
 uses 
  unit1 in 'unit1.pas'
  unit2 in 'unit2.pas'
   ... 
{$else}
 uses 
  unit1 
  unit2
   ...
{$endif}
```

The only problem is whenever you add a new unit, delphi erases your `ifdef package` at the top.

Comment: I dunno dude, this solution may prove too cumbersome for your co-workers to absorb.

Comment: Are you really talking to yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

Every time I have to put conditionals into a project file I do this:

```
program a;

uses
  ACondUnits;

...
```

```
unit ACondUnits;

interface

uses
{$IFDEF UseD7MM}
  Delphi7MM;
{$ELSE}
  FastMM4;
{$ENDIF}

implementation

end.
```

Maybe this trick works in packages too. Never tried.